# How to get the background colour of CTabCtrl?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, tabs

I have a `CTabCtrl` on my dialog, and it has several labels (`CStatic`) on them. The problem is, the tab control has a white background, and the labels have grey backgrounds. I know why - the parent of the labels is actually the dialog, not the tab control. However, I should be able to use `CWnd::OnCtlColor` to provide a custom background brush for the labels:

```
HBRUSH MyDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC *pDC, CWnd *pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hBrush = __super::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    const int dialogId = pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID();
    if (dialogId == IDC_MY_CONTROL)
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        hBrush = m_nullBrush;
    }

    return hBrush;
}
```

Here I use `m_nullBrush` to provide a brush to paint the background of the labels with, the only trouble is, I don't know how to get the tab's background colour, and instead have got it hardcoded with `m_nullBrush.CreateStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);`.

Even if I re-parent the labels onto the tab control, they still end up with a grey background (even though the tab control has a white background).

How do I retrieve the background colour of a `CTabCtrl`?

Comment: I have an MFC application with CTabCtrl and never had to deal with background color of controls. The big difference maybe is that it's using child dialogs that contain the controls.

Comment: What is the hierachy? CTabCtrl is parent to CDialog, which is parent to your controls? And the CDialog background colour is automatically white?

Comment: No, CTabCtrl and child dialogs are both child of main dialog. And yes background is white (or grey if you use classical Windows theme).

Comment: In fact it's not enough, see details in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can put your controls in a child dialog and you must enable theme for this child dialog using `EnableThemeDialogTexture`.

```
#include "Uxtheme.h"

...

BOOL CTabDemoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    COneDlg* OneDlg= new COneDlg;
    OneDlg->Create(IDD_ONE, this);
    AddPage(OneDlg, L"One");

    return TRUE;
}

void CTabDemoDlg::AddPage(CDialog *Dialog, const wchar_t* Title)
{
    if (IsAppThemed())
        EnableThemeDialogTexture(*Dialog, ETDT_ENABLETAB);  

    CRect Rect;
    TabCtl.GetWindowRect(Rect);

    Rect.top+= 20;
    Rect.InflateRect(-4, -4);

    ScreenToClient(Rect);

    Dialog->MoveWindow(Rect);

    TabCtl.InsertItem(0, Title);
}

IDD_ONE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 224, 111
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "Check1",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,20,16,39,10
    LTEXT           "Static",IDC_STATIC,20,36,19,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,20,48,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,84,16,50,14
END
```